# Additional methods to the generated Panache REST Data resource using repository pattern

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm using Quarkus with Hibernate Reactive and Panache REST Data. I'm using the *Repository pattern*. I would like to use the `PanacheRepositoryResource` and add a custom endpoint that calls a method in the `EntityRepository`, but I don't know how to inject the `entityRepository` since it is an interface.

```java
    @ResourceProperties
    public interface EntityResource extends PanacheRepositoryResource<EntityRepository, Entity, Long> {
        @GET
        @Path("/customMethod")
        default Uni<List<Entity>> repositoryMethod() {
            return entityRepository.customMethod(); // <-- How can I inject my repository?
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the issue with injecting the repository interface?

Comment: @geoand maybe I missed something, but I cannot use the `@Inject` annotation because the resource is also declared as an interface and fields in interfaces require initialization; at the same time I cannot declare use constructor injection because I cannot declare a constructor in an interface either.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    @ResourceProperties
    public interface EntityResource extends PanacheRepositoryResource<EntityRepository, Entity, Long> {
        @GET
        @Path("/customMethod")
        default Uni<List<Entity>> repositoryMethod() {
            return CDI.current().select(EntityRepository.class).get().customMethod();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Will this works also with native runtime out-of-the-box?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it will in native mode.